# Is it possible to write a Python script that converts a csv file to a xml file with a specific format?

Tags: python, xml, csv

I have a CSV file with a list of data.The file has about 2000 lines and is structured like the following:

```
Data Source Name, Date & Time, Value
```

I want to take this data and create a script that can format the data into a XML file with the following format:

```
<?XML version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<value sample_date="Date" units="" results="value1"  source_name=""/>
<value sample_date="Date" units="" results="value1 Time" source_name=""/>
<value sample_date="Date" units="" results="value2" source_name=""/>
<value sample_date="Date" units="" results="value2 Time" source_name="" />
```

What commands or libraries would be useful to do this in Python?

Comment: Of course it's possible. It's just the transformation of bits on a computer.

Answer (score 2):

I think Pandas library is what you are looking for. You can load a CSV file into a dataset and then export to the xml file.
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_xml.html

Comment: Stock python has both a CSV parsing module and XML modules. No need for a large third-party package.